How to handle errors by JavaScript side in Pyodide
I'd like to catch errors thrown by Python side in Pyodide. To handle them in JavaScript side, i.e. use try-catch syntax in JS, how should I get the exception object?
For example, when NameError is occurred, the way to check its type by JS side is preferred.
try {
  pyodide.runPython(code)
} catch (e) {
  // Is this available?
  if (e instanceof NameError) { // Use Python's exception types
    ... // handle NameError
  } else if (e instanceof IndexError) {
    ...
  }
}

